# Data not saving correctly

Tags: php, html

So this is part of my code. My problem is for the save button, it does not save my data correctly. It inserted a fixed data regardless the choices I've made in the dropdown. Is there anything wrong with this code? Thank you.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class ="wrapper">
            <h1>Registration</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <h3> Select the relative fields</h3>
            <select name="programme" >
                <option selected disabled>Programmes</option>

                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM programmes_list";
                    $result =  mysqli_query($link, $query);
                    while($rows1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $programmeID = $rows1['programme_no'];
                    $rowsData1 = $rows1['programme_name'];
                    ?>
                        <option value ="<?php echo $programmeID; ?>"><?php echo $rowsData1; ?></option>

                    <?php   
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <select name="intake" >
                <option selected disabled>Intake</option>
                <?php
                    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM intakes";
                    $result2 =  mysqli_query($link, $query2);
                    while($rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                    $intakeID = $rows2['intake_no'];
                    $rowsData2 = $rows2['intake_list'];
                    ?>
                        <option value ="<?php echo $intakeID; ?>"><?php echo $rowsData2; ?></option>

                    <?php   
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" />
            <table border="1" class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Subject Codes</th>
                    <th>Subject Name</th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                    $programmeName =$_POST['programme'];
                    $intakeName =$_POST['intake'];

                    $query3 = "SELECT subject_list.subject_code, subject_list.subjects
                            FROM subject_list
                            WHERE subject_list.programme_id= '$programmeName'
                            AND subject_list.intake_id= '$intakeName'";
                    $result3 =  mysqli_query($link, $query3);
                    while($rows3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
                    $subjectCode = $rows3['subject_code'];
                    $subjectName = $rows3['subjects'];
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                         <td><?php echo $subjectCode; ?></td>
                         <td><?php echo $subjectName; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php   
                    }
                    }


                ?>

            </table>
            <br>
            <h4>Please enter your desired subjects with the respective subject codes.</h4>
            <h4>(Enter comma-> ',' for multiple selections)</h4>
            <input type="text" name="subjects_selected" value="">
            <input type="submit" name="enter" class="enter" />
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['enter'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
                $subjectSelected = $_POST['subjects_selected'];

                if($subjectSelected !=''){
                //Insert Query of SQL
                $query4 = mysqli_query($link, "insert into registered(programme_registered, intake_registered, subjects_registered) values ( '$rowsData1', '$rowsData2', '$subjectSelected')");
                echo "<br/><br/><span>You ave registered your subjects!!</span>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why you put the insert logic in `<form>` tag?

Comment: $query4 = mysqli_query($link, "insert into registered(programme_registered, intake_registered, subjects_registered) values ( '".$rowsData1."', '".$rowsData2."', '".$subjectSelected."')");

Comment: because without the form tag my data cant be retrieved into the table in the my page, meaning the button "submit" wont work

Comment: what fixed data you get ?

Comment: @Nishit Manjarawala it still did not work. Data saved from dropdown is still fixed

Comment: @Kit if you echo out just $_POST['programme']; what you get ?

Comment: @koo27 my choices for "prgramme" dropdown is cert , diploma and degree while my "intake" dropdown choices are january 2015, march 2015, june 2015 and august 2015. So everything i pressed the submit button, it will save degree and august 2015, no matter which 1 i choose for dropdown

Comment: @koo27 where do I echo $_POST['programme']; ? inside the if(isset($_POST['enter'])) loop?

Comment: ok so it seems it takes only the **last** value in the select list , right ?
yes you can echo inside the isset() just to see what you get from the post.
in the select , the options are corrected ? I mean the html code shows the correct values and correct options name from the database ?

Comment: @koo27 for the dropdowns the choices are retrieved from my database. I did not enter the choices in html but into my db. Yes, they display correct choices when I click the dropdowns. The problem is just that it saves the the last value in the select list, like what you said. And also, when I echo $_POST['programme']; , it will just say undefined: index

Comment: seems there shouldn't be any reason why it doesn't take the correct option, since it's not a multi select. Please try to put the logic outside the form, maybe using another file where to show the results (just for testing) and let's see what happend. Please just echo out the $_POST['programme'] without query anything from the database, so we get directly the option selected.

Comment: i mean if i echo $_POST['programme']; it will just show undefined: index error and it did not diplay any option selected